# Adsense API getting 'Error: Login Required'

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, adsense-api

I'm using the API Explorer tool to create some request urls for google adsense. Here is the request url that the explorer tool generated that gives a response of today's earnings: `https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/reports?startDate=today&endDate=today&accountId=MY_ACCOUNT_ID&metric=EARNINGS&key=MY_API_KEY`

However, when I try to use this url in the browser or in my code it gives this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing it use this url. I have activated adsense apis on my google developer console.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` parameter is the public API key for accessing public data.

The `access_token` parameter is used for accessing private user data.

In your case you are trying to access your private account and should be using an access token.

To obtain an access token you need to authentication your application using either Oauth2 or a service account.  Once you have obtained an access token and send that with your request as so:

> https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/reports?startDate=today&endDate=today&accountId=MY_ACCOUNT_ID&metric=EARNINGS&access_token=YourAccessToken

Answer (score -2):

You need to replace `MY_API_KEY` with your API key, and MY_ACCOUNT_ID in same fashion.

Comment: Yes of course. I'm not show that here for obvious reasons. My code actually has both those in place

Comment: Then you probably need to take this up with Google! Good luck.